# Reducing the space between the \title and the first line of the the abstract in IEEEtran

Tags: spacing, titles, ieeetran

I am trying to reduce the space between the title and the abstract (the paper have no authors). IEEETran style is being used.
I tried the `\vspace` command but it didn't work, any ideas, recommendations?

Just to be clear I have something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is for test text...
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

I want to reduce the vertical space between "Some Title" and "This is...."

Comment: The `\maketitle` command is in my opinion one of the most annoying ones, with too much restrictions, together with `abstract` environments` I always generate a titlepage from scratch, without `\title`. So, where did you try to apply `\vspace`

Comment: The space is reserved for the `\author`.  Why do you not want to put your name on the document?

Comment: Use `\author{}`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies but it is a blind submission (i can't have the name of any of the authors there). I even tried to use an empty field for the author and eat the space before and after it but it didn't work. As for the \vspace I had put them after the title and before \begin{abstract} but they didn't work as well.

Comment: I don't see the white space as a problem: the final paper will have `\author`s in that space. If it bothers you, you could consider using `\author{Some dummy text}`.

Comment: @mvkorpel, yes the final paper will have the author in it but at the current point of the submission process, there should be no authors in the paper (not even dummy ones) and the space between the abstract and the title is large and we need to shrink it.

Comment: @Anderson: If it is not the final version and only an intermediate state, I wonder, why you worry about some space there? Do you have a page limit? Well, all efforts to reduce the space will break if you have to insert `\author` then.

Comment: Well, an ugly hack could be `\title{Some Title\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}}`, but I hate such manual shifts

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, u are right we have a page limit and the problem is that we have run out of space totally and we can save some space from  reducing the vertical space, I know what u are saying but adding the authors later is a different story (they have some other policies and page limits). I will try that hack and inform you. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you very the command which you provided to me worked like charm. Problem solved thank you again.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Which IEEE publication has double blind submission?

Comment: @percusse the ones that I know about are MobiHoc and MobiCom

Comment: They are not IEEE no?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hey unsung hero, wann write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Well, what should I post? `\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}`? ;-)

Answer (score 9):

As has been pointed out in the comments, changing the appearance of a journal template is discouraged. A journal wants to have a consistent look.

If you are absolutely sure you want to change something, you can do some kind of a hack ([Dr. Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer) pointed it out). In the example below, i introduced some positive space to get the text away from the title; using negative space you get the text closer to the title.

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\title{Some Title\vspace{6em}}
\author{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: oahMaketitleSpace]

If you want to know more about changing the apppearance of titles of own documents, have a look at [Customize a titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907).